# Firebase-Cloud-Function Thumbnail Store to Dynamic Database Path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm successfully using the generate-thumbnail cloud function. My code is correctly saving the resized image as 'thumb_', storing the resized image into the correct storage location, and writing the downloadURL to my realtime database.

The cloud function is saving the downloadURL to ref('images')

```
return admin.database().ref('images').push({path: fileUrl, thumbnail: thumbFileUrl});
```

**My Questions:**

***1. How can i change the database reference to be dynamic so it will save the downloadURL to a path in the database based on the album the user selected to upload?***

Something like:

```
return admin.database().ref('\albums\{albumId}').push({path: fileUrl, thumbnail: thumbFileUrl});
```

***2. Can i pass the albumId from my client to my cloud function as a variable?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem by making my Storage hierarchy match my Database hierarchy.

When a user uploads a picture, the cloud function triggered on the storage event gets the file path (fileDir). I store the fileDir into a string

```
const dbPath = String(fileDir);
```

Then I push the downloadURL to dbPath in my database ref (since my storage hierarchy matches my database hierarchy) this works.

```
return admin.database().ref('/' + dbPath).push({hiRes: fileUrl, photoURL: thumbFileUrl});
```